# Compare NSString to ameliorate OCR

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsstring, tesseract

I'm working on an application in objective C (osX) in which I use an 'OCR' - I use 'Tesseract' which is really good. The problem is, there is some expressions that are not well recognized. In order to get a good result, I would try to make some string comparison and changes.

In other words, my algorithm would look like this :

```
myNewString = @"tept String";
if ( myNewString isEqualAt80%orMoreToString : @"test String" )
{
    myNewString = @"test String";
}
```

But how could I test if my 'NSString' is at minimum equal at 80% or more than another string ?

Thank you for you help !

Comment: You might be interested by the concept of [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: @ Cyrille - Thanks, cool algorithm!

Comment: @Cyrille I didn't heard of this algorithm before, looks really good :) Thank you !